# Is it possible to authorize a Facebook user to send me a private message into my Inbox?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook, message

I definitely know that you can't send a message to other users, but is it possible to allow users to send messages to me?

Lik something similar to Twitter's direct messaging API, where the user authenticates my app to allow them to send messages through the app to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Sending a private message to a user using graph API is impossible at this time.

You CAN however use this (using Javascript SDK): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/